# RxJava: Is it possible to build in Completable execution into doOnSuccess or similar

Tags: java, rx-java2

When some asunchronous operations need to be performed within Rx operations chain:

```
    private static Single<String> process(final String s) {
        return Single.just(s)
                .map(String::toUpperCase)
                .doOnSuccess(str -> saveValue1(str) // asynchronous op 1)
                .doOnSuccess(str -> saveValue2(str) // asynchronous op 2);
    }
```

Is it possible to write alternative of Rx chain without `flatMap` or `blockingGet`, which builds in the execution of Completable methods `saveValue1`, `saveValue2` etc. into chain.

```
    private static Single<String> process(final String s) {
        return Single.just(s)
                .map(String::toUpperCase)
                .doOnSuccess(str -> saveValue1(str).blockingGet() // asynchronous op 1)
                .doOnSuccess(str -> saveValue2(str).blockingGet() // asynchronous op 2);
    }
```

or

```
private static Single<String> process(final String s) {
    return Single.just(s)
            .map(String::toUpperCase)
            .flatMap(str -> saveValue1(str).toSingleDefault(str) // asynchronous op 1)
            .flatMap(str -> saveValue2(str).toSingleDefault(str) // asynchronous op 2);
}
```

Example to reproduce:

```
package com.eisgroup.genesis.policy.core.lifecycle.commands.quote;

import io.reactivex.Completable;
import io.reactivex.Single;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;

public class Test {
    // some variables to check that asynchronous save works
    static String s1;
    static String s2; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = process("test").blockingGet();
        Assert.hasText(s, "TEST");
        Assert.hasText(s1, "TEST");
        Assert.hasText(s2, "TEST");
    }   


    // some fake examples to show asynchronous save
    private static Completable saveValue1(String s) {
        return Completable.defer(() -> {
            s1 = s;
            return Completable.complete();
        });
    }

    private static Completable saveValue2(String s) {
        return Completable.defer(() -> {
            s2 = s;
            return Completable.complete();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return Single.just(s)
                .map(String::toUpperCase)
                .flatMapCompletable(string -> Completable.mergeArray(
                        saveValue1(string).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),
                        saveValue2(string).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())));
```

`saveValue1` and `saveValue2` will run in parallel ok? Don't know if that's what you want, but for efficiency and speed I do encourage it.

Comment: The problem is that I want to return a Single<String> as a result of RX chain. Sorry I havent explicitly metioned it. I have added more details

Comment: It returns a `Single` now with the data when the two Completables have completed

Comment: Yep, now it does, it's working solution) But now it contains `flatMap`. I do not like `flatMap` because of the intention not to map (transform) the original string, but just to execute some side efects in the RX chain.  Your solution is like my example with `flatMap`, maybe a little more efficient. 
I would like to have method like `peek()` in Stream API but with some sort of synchrinization. It's possiblle that's no way to do it other way in RX now, other than with map/flatMap operation

Comment: I've never used Rx like this, I just edited my original post because you wanted to keep it a `Single`. I would never return a `Single` there but a `Completable`. The fact that you need to return a `Single` tells me that there's something wrong with the design of your stream. Maybe you would like to specify why you need to have a `Single` there? I'll amend my post to return a `Completable` for now as I consider the current posted solution non-elegant.

Comment: "maybe a little more efficient" --> this solution uses proper usage of schedulers to achieve parallelism of the two requests and propagation of the Completion downstream whereas in your approach you're blocking the stream completely with `blockingGet`, which is a method only meant to be used in unit testing. How would you achieve parallelism with your approach to achieve same efficiency?

Comment: "maybe a little more efficient" -> it was not about the `blockingGet()` approach, It was about the second example with `.flatMap(str -> saveValue1(str).toSingleDefault(str)`. Blocking get was only about showind desired behaviour from functional point of the code, not reactive.

Comment: And my situation why I need this is next: I have a REST endpoint, let's say `update`. It modifies entity (for example updates date of the last modification) then stores the entity in DB and returns this entity on response. But I need to store part of the entity as separate calls to DB (in Cassandra in different tables). And `save` returns Completable.

Comment: "But I need to store part of the entity as separate calls to DB" -> That's how the Rx chain continues there, before the `flatMapCompletable` at the end, you need to do all the operations you need before the Completables save the data at the end. The other option is to subscribe for database changes, filter and start doing the things you need to do. Good luck!